# How to sort Firestore query results with whereField is using arrayContainsAny and in

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

## The Problem

I'm looking for a way to sort Firestore query results that use `arrayContainsAny` or `in` for the `whereField` clause.

Every time I set up a paginated query and process the first batch, I get different results back in different order.

The Firestore documentation says

> You cannot order your query by any field included in an equality (=) or in clause.

I've tried ordering by `name` field and first ordering by `categories` and then other fields.
Whatever I enter does not seem to be used for the query.

## Example

Let's imagine the following data structure:

```
brands/
    chiquita/
        products/
            banana: {
                name: "Banana",
                categories: ["fruits", "berries"]
            }
    365organic/
        products/
            romaine: {
                name: "Romaine Lettuce",
                categories: ["lettuce", "vegetables"]
            }
    mars/
        products/
            snickers: {
                name: "Snickers",
                categories: ["chocolate bars"]
            }
```

Here's my Firestore query in swift:

```
var query = self.database.collectionGroup("products")
    .whereField("categories", arrayContainsAny: ["fruits", "vegetables"])
    .orderBy("name")
    .limit(to: 25)

    // lastSnapshot is the last doc's snapshot or nil if called the first time
    if let lastSnapshot = lastSnapshot { 
        query = query.start(afterDocument: lastSnapshot)
    }
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the specific results of a queries that don't work the way you expect?  Also be sure your code is checking for errors, and show the error if there is one.

Comment: I've been digging deeper over the past 24 hours and found an issue in the application logic that caused the sorting to be not applied. After fixing that I'm getting back the items sorted consistently!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging deeper through the client logic I found an issue that caused the sorting to not be applied client-side.

After fixing that I'm getting back the items sorted consistently!